# Edit String in XML file

Tags: java, android, string, nullpointerexception, resources

I am trying to create a user profile section in my app. In my Login Activity, I ask for the username from FirebaseAUTH.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() and save it in a string.

In my xml file for the main activity, I put a textView with a string containing a placeholder.

I tried both in the Login and the Main Activity Java files to .setText .format etc, but the text simply doesnt change..

Any hints on how to solve this?

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private HomeFragment hf;
    private WebViewFragment wvf;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

     firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
     if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() != null) {
        String name = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
        final TextView profile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_section);
        profile.setText("Test");
    }
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.vreeni.firebaseauthentiction, PID: 6060
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vreeni.firebaseauthentiction/com.example.vreeni.firebaseauthentication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2822)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2897)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1598)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6563)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.vreeni.firebaseauthentication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)

Comment: Do you want to change a string resource? It's not possible. But you can change the text in a TextView or an EditText.

Comment: yes thats what I wanted..Hmmm, how would I do that? I want to have a section in the navigation drawer saying Username followed by the username that can be retrieved from firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check is your textview is with same ID in XML file, as defined here or not ?

Comment: It is the same, yes. I also tried it with the text being a placeholder and there not even being a text,
 but same result.<TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/user_name" android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

Comment: You can use a separate txt file to store "dynamic" strings. Or a database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a simple example right at the top of [this resource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         final TextView helloTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
         helloTextView.setText(R.string.user_greeting);
     }
 }
```

If you still have problems, please provide your code.

Comment: updated with code and error message

Comment: Your variable profile is null. Please also provide your activity_main.xml.